# Combine two callbacks into one return

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverless-framework

So I have this code:

```
module.exports.getEstimate = (event, context, callback) => {
 var data = JSON.parse(event.body);

 lalamove.getQuotation(data ,context, function(err, llm_data){
  callback(null,llm_data)
 });
};
```

So it calls lalamove.getQuotation function and returns an object:

`{ "totalFee": "108", "totalFeeCurrency": "PHP" }`

Now, I have added a new function, that returns this object:

`{ "totalFee": "10", "totalFeeCurrency": "PHP" }`

from a different function so I thought I should push them in one array and then that is when I would call the callback but it does not work, this is what I have tried

```
module.exports.getEstimate = (event, context, callback) => {
var data = JSON.parse(event.body);
var response = []

lalamove.getQuotation(data ,context, function(err, llm_data){
  const llm_obj = { "lalamove": llm_data }
  response.push(llm_obj);
});

inhouse.getQuotation(data ,context, function(err, ih_data){
  const ih_obj = {"inhouse": ih_data }
  response.push(ih_obj);
});

callback(null,response);
};
```

and what I want to be the response is like this:

```
["lalamove": { "totalFee": "108", "totalFeeCurrency": "PHP" },
"inhouse": { "totalFee": "10", "totalFeeCurrency": "PHP" }]
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to World's Javascript world - Callback hell.

We have some options for your case: Callback hell, async lib, Promise, async/await...

Callback hell: Call a async function in a callback

```
module.exports.getEstimate = (event, context, callback) => {
  var data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  var response = []

  lalamove.getQuotation(data, context, function (err, llm_data) {
    const llm_obj = { "lalamove": llm_data }
    response.push(llm_obj);

    // lalamove.getQuotation done!
    // call next action
    inhouse.getQuotation(data, context, function (err, ih_data) {
      const ih_obj = { "inhouse": ih_data }
      response.push(ih_obj);

      // inhouse.getQuotation done!
      // call the last action
      callback(null, response);
    });
  });
};
```

Async lib: [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)
You can use `waterfall` function to do actions in order, and `parallel` if order is not matter.

```
module.exports.getEstimate = (event, context, callback) => {
  var data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  var response = []

  async.parallel([
    function (next) {
      lalamove.getQuotation(data, context, function (err, llm_data) {
        // TODO: check err object
        const llm_obj = { "lalamove": llm_data }
        response.push(llm_obj);

        // lalamove.getQuotation done!
        // do next action
        next();
      });
    },
    function (next) {
      inhouse.getQuotation(data, context, function (err, ih_data) {
        const ih_obj = { "inhouse": ih_data }
        response.push(ih_obj);

        // inhouse.getQuotation done!
        // do next action
        next()
      });
    }
  ], function (err) {
    // TODO: check err object
    // call the last action
    callback(null, response);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `callback(null,response)` will not wait for those two callback functions to finish. You can use Promise and use `Promise.all(objs).then(function)` to wait for all promises finish and run.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping two quotation calls in `Promise`, then utilise `Promise.all` to wait for both of them to be completed, then return the result to the `callback`

```
module.exports.getEstimate = (event, context, callback) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(event.body);

    // wrap quotation calls in `Promise`
    Promise.all([
        new Promise(resolve => lalamove.getQuotation(data, context, (err, lalamove) => resolve({ lalamove }))),
        new Promise(resolve => inhouse.getQuotation (data, context, (err, inhouse ) => resolve({ inhouse  }))),
    ]).then(response => {
        // return the result back to `callback`
        callback(null, response);
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) and the async / await syntax.

For example:

```
const util = require("util");

module.exports.getEstimate = async (event, context, callback) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(event.body);
    try { 
        let response = await Promise.all([ util.promisify(lalamove.getQuotation)(data, context), 
                                           util.promisify(inhouse.getQuotation)(data, context) ]);
        callback(null, response);
    } catch (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
};
```

We can also do something similar, but without async / await:

```
const util = require("util");

const getEstimate = (event, context, callback) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(event.body);
    Promise.all([util.promisify(lalamove.getQuotation)(data, context), 
                util.promisify(inhouse.getQuotation)(data, context)])
        .then(response => callback(null, response))
        .catch(err => callback(err));
};
```